# How to parse in javascript locale date string to iso string for any format

Tags: javascript, luxon

Let's say my default language in the browser is Ukrainian.

```
const dateStr = new Date().toLocaleString();
console.log(dateStr); //28.02.2024, 23:35:40
```

Now I want to parse this `dateStr` back to Date;

```
const dateObj = new Date(dateStr);
// Invalid date
```

I know that I can use `luxon.fromFormat` for example, but then I should know the current string format for the locale. Is there way to pares any Locale String back to Date or ISO String?

Comment: I don't think so. If you want parsable dates, don't use locale strings.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry can you elaborate? I need to print the current date for any region/language. So if the current browser is in Ukraine I print "28.02.2024, 23:35:40". How can I parse this string back to ISO string?

Comment: You can print whatever you like, but don't try to parse it. Save the date in ISO format somewhere else, like a data attribute.

Comment: Or even save the date as a number you get back from `getTime()`,  like @Barmar says keeps things internally as UTC, time is a universal , it doesn't care what country your from.

Comment: @Barmar you are right. There is no way to parse the locale date string back to ISO